# Efficient way to check the text periodically using JS

Tags: javascript

I want to to read text file periodically whether it has expected text or not and i have written below code. without using setInterval, Is there any smart way we can do it like inside if(this.status===200){} itself or anything else?

```
currentIntervalId=setInterval( function() { readTextFile("file1.txt",getTextData); }, 2000 );
function readTextFile(file,callback)
{
    console.log('Reading file..')
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "textFiles/"+file, true);
    rawFile.onload = function (){

      if(this.status===200){
          getTextData(this.responseText);     
        }

    }
    rawFile.send();
   }
function getTextData(txtStatus)
{

    txtStatus=txtStatus.trim();


   if(txtStatus.toUpperCase()==='COMPLETE')//here not matching
   {
       console.log("Task done..")
       clearInterval(currentIntervalId);

       makeTaskComplete();
   }
   else{

    console.log("Task Not done..")

   }

}
```

Comment: This code was used in another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862591/string-is-not-matching-in-if-condition)  `(:` how do I know that? I need a more social life xD.

Comment: @Ele i feel, its a another geniune  question :) for which i have no answer

Comment: Yes, it's a genuine one